# How to discover which files exist in a folder

Tags: c, file

I have written a program, where it takes an input file, does some operations on it and gives its corresponding output file. i.e., for inp1.txt output is out1.txt, for inp2.txt output is out2.txt and so on, both in different folders.

Right now I have used a file_count variable and have used switch case method, to open the particular file.

The problem is, if I add one more file to the folder, then I have to re-edit the program with another case statement.

Please suggest me the usage of directory pointer in , I browsed all over the net but didnt get an exact solution.

Thanks a lot in anticipation.

Comment: where is your written program?

Answer (score 2):

There's no way to read the contents of a directory using only standard C APIs, so you'll have to use platform-specific APIs instead:

- On *nix systems, you use [`opendir(3)`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/opendir)/[`readdir(3)`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/readdir)/[`closedir(3)`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/closedir) to read the contents of a directory.
- On Windows systems, you use [`FindFirstFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364418%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)/[`FindNextFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364428%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)/[`FindClose`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364413%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

If you know the file names in advance ie. they follow a pattern like this: `f1.txt f2.txt fn.txt` then you can loop over the files:

```
for (int i = 0 -> num_files)
    char * filename;
    filename = create_your_filename(i)
    open(filename)
    dostuff
    close(filename)
```

you can follow the same pattern or even edit the filename for the output files. 
Otherwise you can also call the program with all the input files in the command:

```
 your_program *.txt
```

Then all of the file names will appear in `argv[]`, which you can iterate over.

Answer (score 0):

you have to find the files in input folder in runtime before processing. you can sort the files by extension,file name,created date etc...

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple function that show you if a file (in parameters) is in the path you put in argument.

Return 0 if file exit, 1 if not.

```
int             is_file_enabled(char *path, char *filename)
{
  char          exec[255], line[255];

  sprintf(exec, "ls %s | grep \"%s\"", path, filename);
  FILE*         cmd_res = popen(exec, "r");
  if (cmd_res != NULL)
    while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), cmd_res) != NULL)
      if (line != NULL) { pclose(cmd_res); return 0; }
  pclose(cmd_res);
  return 1;
}
```